# Replace "Undefined" with Text

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am trying to replace "undefined" when displaying an array that has become empty.

Here is a simplified version of the program, in which the user will decrement the array each time the button is pushed. When the array is empty, if the user keeps on pressing the button, I would like the text to replace "undefined."

I have played with "while" statements, as well as "typeof", but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<script>
  basket = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Pears'];

  function showFruit() {
    var i = 0; // the index of the current item to show
    fruitDisplay = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('fruit')
            .innerHTML = basket[i++]; // get the item and increment
        if (i == basket.length) i = 0; 
                                   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
    }, 100); //speed to display items

    var endFruitDisplay = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(fruitDisplay);

        var index = basket.indexOf(document.getElementById('fruit').innerHTML);
        basket.splice(index, 1); //remove last shown

    }, 1000); //stop display after x milliseconds

    remain = basket.length;
    document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = remain;

    return showFruit;
}

    //if (typeof(basket) == undefined) {
    //fruit = 'Finished';
    //} 

</script>

    <h1><span id = 'fruit'></span> </h1>
    Remaining: <span id="remaining"></span>


 <button onclick="showFruit()">Random Fruit</button>
```

Comment: suggest you just check if array has length and not do anything or advise user if it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test if the array is empty.

```
if (basket.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("fruit").innerHTML = "No fuits left";
} else {
    document.getElementById('fruit')
        .innerHTML = basket[i];
    i = (i + 1) % basket.length // increment with wraparound
}
```

Comment: Worked nicely -- thank you! Amazing how much time I spent on something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

I see the commented code ... try ...

```
if (typeof basket === "undefined") {
  fruit = 'Finished';
}
```

Basically, this is the proper way to compare `typeof` against `undefined`.  Although your variable typeof will not be undefined, so ...

You can also check against the array length ...

```
if (basket.length === 0) {
  fruit = 'Finished';
}
```

Comment: `basket` won't be undefined. It will just be an empty array after all the fruits are removed from it.

Comment: Yes, I was adding that.  Thanks for being patient.